# Passing param to CSV file upload - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

Part of my app deals with updating inventories for vendors. The vendor will do this through CSV import. Essentially, a vendor navigates to the show view for a particular store and this is what they see:

```
<h2>Import an Inventory</h2>

<%= form_tag import_inventory_items_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :store_id, :value => @store.id %>
<%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

This of course to the import action in my inventory_items controller:

```
def import
        InventoryItem.import(params[:file], params[:store_id])
        redirect_to admin_index_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
end
```

This calls `import` in the model like so:

```
def self.import(file, store_id)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_store_id(row[2], :store_id)
inventory_item.update_attributes(row.to_hash.slice(:price))
    end
end
```

This is where I think I'm running into trouble. What I'm trying to do is pass the store_id from @store in the show view to the CSV import methods so that each new record will have a store_id = @store.id. I'm getting this error when I try uploads:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "store_id"
```

I'm sure I'm not passing @store.id down the line correctly, anyone have some insight here?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the html output. Seems to that I'm dropping the ball in my model import method?

```
Processing by InventoryItemsController#import as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"w/YcsZlqxnONZk+z46J7DaU6NRQeV+Czv7pIS4H3u8s=", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000104fa93d0 @original_filename="Products.csv - Sheet1 (2).csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Products.csv - Sheet1 (2).csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/6Q/6QjjMV+aFh4A4orYbGW-nE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20131217-95734-1il2q3s>>, "store_id"=>"{:value=>1}", "commit"=>"Import"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Issue

This

```
inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_store_id(row[2], :store_id)
```

Should be this

```
inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_store_id(row[2], store_id)
```

There shouldn't be a colon - Rails doesn't actually have an issue with `:store_id`, it's valid syntax (try it out in irb), but it's messing up your postgresql because it's obviously not an integer, it's a bit like saying `SELECT :store_id::integer;` if that makes any sense (It's a little confusing with the colons) :)

## Second Issue

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :store_id, :value => @store.id %>
```

should be

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :store_id, @store.id %>
```

Adding the `:value =>` turns it into a hash, as seen by your params -

```
 "store_id"=>"{:value=>1}"
```

It's intuitive to add a :value attribute, but it's actually wrong.

Comment: Sure enough! Thank you for saving me a ton of time and some sanity.

Comment: Oops, one final issue I guess. While this resolved the error, I'm getting inventory_item records created all with store_id = 0. It doesn't appear that the store_id is actually getting passed to the upload. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at your HTML output and your logs, is the HTML correct? (Ie is the store id there?) is it being passed into the controller properly?

Comment: Yes, the HTML looks right. Seems to be a hitch in the model method. I've updated my question with the HTML output.

Comment: @settheline I figured it out.. Check my answer, it's your HTML :)

Comment: Ah you're right! That fixed the store_id issue. The correct store_id is now being committed. Thanks! I'm still trying to figure out why `:price` isn't being updated though....I can put that in another question though if you like. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648371/rails-csv-upload-to-update-records-attribute-not-saved-to-db ....If you have some spare time. Thanks again.