# Rails CSV upload to update records - attribute not saved to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a system for updating `InventoryItem` records using a CSV upload.

I have this controller method:

```
def import
        InventoryItem.import(params[:file], params[:store_id])
        redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
    end

Which of course calls this model method:

def self.import(file, store_id)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code_and_store_id(row[0], store_id)
    inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash.slice(:price))
        end
    end
```

I want to update only the `:price` attribute in the update because and `:code` and `:store_id` won't change. Currently the records being imported have price all as 0.0 (big decimal). Not nil, or the correct value, but 0.0, so clearly I'm doing something wrong to make this work. I know when I do this in the console it looks something like this:

```
inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_by_id(1)
inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => 29.99)
```

Any ideas on why I'm not updating the price attribute correctly?

Comment: Maybe this video will shed some light to your question http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this, it doesn't seem like csv returns symbolized hash keys
and slice doesn't seem to work there. how about this inside your
CSV.foreach loop:

```
inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price"])
```

Comment: Sorry no, didn't mean to imply that in my console example. It's a decimal. Fixed that example.

Comment: Are you saying that I should call `to_f` if `:price` is a decimal?

Comment: I was, but tried it and it didn't need it. Updated my answer to indicate that csv does not return symbol hash keys.

Comment: So this worked, but I can't say I understand why. It seems this will only update price (like I wanted), but how does `["price"]` accomplish this? Also, I've seen slice used in other instances of CSV usage, why does this scenario not allow for slice? Thank you for your help!